# PHP Как убрать вывод значений на страницу

Tags: php, ajax

У меня при выборе даты заполняется выпадающий список.
После нажатия на кнопку submit, значения, которыми заполняется выпадающий список, выводятся на страницу.
Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CallTime').on('change',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: 'CallTime='+$(this).val(),
            success: function(data){
                //alert('qwerty');
                console.log(data);
                $('option', $("#times_option")).remove();
                $("#times_option").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['CallTime']))
    {
        $t="";
        $a=0;
        while($a<10)
        {
            $t .= '<option value="">'.$a.'</option>';
            $a++;
        }
        echo $t;
    }
?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p>Выберите дату:</p>   
        <input type="date" name="CallTime" id="CallTime">
        <p>Выберите время:</p>
        <select name="time" id="times_option"><option></option></select>
        <input type="submit" value="ОК">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полезно отличать ajax-запрос от submit'а формы:

```
if (isset($_POST['CallTime']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']))
```

А так же перенесите обработку в начало файла.